# Node.js XPath example?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xpath, xmldom

I have an XML data and to read I am using 'xpath' and 'xmldom'. I am fetching `relativePath` value but it's giving only first value(`/abc/`) 3 times. I am not able to get other value.

```
var xpath = require('xpath')
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser

var le = `
<content>
<data>
<content-item>
<relativePath>/abc/</relativePath>
<text>abc</text>
<leaf>false</leaf>
<lastModified>2018-10-16</lastModified>
</content-item>
<content-item>
<relativePath>/defghi/</relativePath>
<text>defghi</text>
<leaf>false</leaf>
<lastModified>2018-06-23</lastModified>
</content-item>
<content-item>
<relativePath>/jklmn/</relativePath>
<text>jklmn</text>
<leaf>false</leaf>
<lastModified>2019-02-27</lastModified>
</content-item>`;

var doc = new dom().parseFromString(le);
var nodes = xpath.select("//content-item", doc); 
  nodes.forEach( (n, i) => {
    var title = xpath.select("string(//relativePath)", n);

    console.log(title);

  });
```

Final output:

```
/abc/
/abc/
/abc/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking the string value of a nodeset, which is by definition the string value of the first node.  Iterate over the selected nodes in JavaScript, and only take the string value of each individually rather than call the XPath `string()` function on the entire nodeset collectively.

It's also unclear why you'd want a nested loop rather than a single loop over all `relativePath` elements, but perhaps that was an artifact of the reduction of your complete program to a posted example.  In any case, if you wish to restrict your inner loop to only those `relativePath` elements beneath the current `content-item` context node, use `.//relativePath` instead.

Finally, your XML is not well-formed.

### Node.js xmldom / xpath working example

I've fixed the above problems in the example below (and indented the XML to ease reading):

```
var xpath = require('xpath')
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser

var le = `
<content>
  <data>
    <content-item>
      <relativePath>/abc/</relativePath>
      <text>abc</text>
      <leaf>false</leaf>
      <lastModified>2018-10-16</lastModified>
    </content-item>
    <content-item>
      <relativePath>/defghi/</relativePath>
      <text>defghi</text>
      <leaf>false</leaf>
      <lastModified>2018-06-23</lastModified>
    </content-item>
    <content-item>
      <relativePath>/jklmn/</relativePath>
      <text>jklmn</text>
      <leaf>false</leaf>
      <lastModified>2019-02-27</lastModified>
    </content-item>
  </data>
</content>`;

var doc = new dom().parseFromString(le);
var nodes = xpath.select("//relativePath", doc); 
nodes.forEach( (n, i) => {
  console.log(n.textContent);
});
```

### Output

```
/abc/
/defghi/
/jklmn/
```

as requested.

Comment: can you please give a example

Comment: @santosh: Answer updated with your code corrected as requested.

Comment: thanks for the update but this give's only the "relativePath" if i need "lastModified"  how to fetch 
I got am an example but I don't know whether it correct way to do
nodes.forEach( (n, i) => {
 xpath.select('//relativePath', n)[i].firstChild.data
xpath.select('//lastModified', n)[i].firstChild.data
});

Comment: @santosh: Sorry, but your question clearly indicated interest in `relativePath`, so that's what I showed.  Can't chase variations here indefinitely.  Please ask a new question and be clear exactly what your actual goal is if you now wish to access another item and cannot apply this working example to your new requirement.  Thank you.